# How to authenticate once in google drive api

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, google-drive-api

I have this problem about google drive. This is my application
[image]

As you can see here. I want to browse and upload the file to google drive. But every time I upload a file i need to allow and copy the authentication to my application.. like here

[image]

Is it possible to allow access once? Is there any other way to fix this? Can i automatically allow access to the authentication code within my application so that i may not use the browser??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to request is "offline" access. This will give you a refresh token that you can use to get a fresh access token forever, or until the user revokes it.

See https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials for a .NET example.

Answer (score 4):

if you are running server app how about using OAuth2? You won't need to use users console.

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
     .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
     .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
     .setServiceAccountId("[[SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL]]")
     .setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.DRIVE, DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE,
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile")
     .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(Auth.keyFile)
     .setServiceAccountUser("[[impersonateduser@domain]]")
     .build();
credentials.refreshToken();
```

and I've found this blog about OAuth2:

http://blog.databigbang.com/automated-browserless-oauth-authentication-for-twitter/

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at **Authorizing with stored credentials** within [Authorization for Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth). Basically you can access the account as long as the stored access_token does not expire.

Comment: ahm i check the source code and run it. although the allow request is gone. It still opens up a browser to get the token..